# Why this slowness of .Call in R?

Tags: r, haskell, dll

I have created a DLL with Haskell. It exports two functions:

- `readXLSX`: takes as arguments a xlsx file name, a sheet name, and returns the contents of the sheet in a R list
- `readXLSXbig`: no argument, this is the same function as `readXLSX` but it always read the sheet named `Sheet 1` of a file named `big.xlsx`

First, let's try `readXLSX` on a small file:

```
> library(readxl)
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   readxl = read_xlsx("example.xlsx", "Sheet1", col_types="list", col_names=FALSE),
+   haskell = .Call("readXLSX", "example.xlsx", "Sheet1"),
+   times=2
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval cld
  readxl 9.294365 9.294365 9.660375 9.660375 10.026385 10.026385     2   b
 haskell 2.164942 2.164942 2.593681 2.593681  3.022419  3.022419     2  a
```

Well, it is faster than `readxl` (not surprising because `readxl` provides more features, and tests for the existence of the file, etc).

Now, let's try on the file `big.xlsx`, which is bigger:

```
> microbenchmark(
+   readxl = read_xlsx("big.xlsx", "Sheet 1", col_types="list", col_names=FALSE),
+   H1 = .Call("readXLSXbig"),
+   H2 = .Call("readXLSX", "big.xlsx", "Sheet 1"), 
+   times=2
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
 readxl  143.74213  143.74213  144.05025  144.05025  144.3584  144.3584     2  a 
     H1   33.38596   33.38596   68.60333   68.60333  103.8207  103.8207     2  a 
     H2 8845.17038 8845.17038 9149.19542 9149.19542 9453.2205 9453.2205     2   b
```

In fact, the results of this benchmark are quite variable (I don't know why) but I always observe the same behaviour: `readXLSXbig` is faster than `readxl` and `readXLSX` is very slower.

Let me recall that `readXLSXbig` does exactly the same thing as `readXLSX`; the only difference is that the file name `big.xlsx` and the sheet name `Sheet 1` are already given in `readXLSXbig`:

```
readXLSXbig :: SEXP V 'R.Vector
readXLSXbig = unsafePerformIO $ do 
  fcellmap <- xlsxSheetToFormattedCellMap "big.xlsx" "Sheet 1"
  formattedCellMapToRList fcellmap fcellToCellValue 0

readXLSX :: SEXP s 'R.String -> SEXP s 'R.String -> SEXP V 'R.Vector
readXLSX file sheet = unsafePerformIO $ do 
  fcellmap <- xlsxSheetToFormattedCellMap (fromSEXP file) (fromSEXP sheet)
  formattedCellMapToRList fcellmap fcellToCellValue 0
```

Why such a difference ? `readXLSX` takes ~9 seconds on the big file while `readXLSXbig` takes only ~70 milliseconds. On the small file `example.xlsx`, we have seen that `readXLSX` takes <3 milliseconds, therefore there are not 9 seconds wasted to read the file name and the sheet name.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable with the information you've provided. It will relate to some interaction between R and your code (or just your code in general), and you didn't provide your code.

Comment: @MikeStanley That's possible but the code is huge. Moreover it intensively uses the `inline-r` library and almost nobody uses this library. It also calls some C functions with the FFI... I understand your remark but maybe someone could have an idea of the cause.

Comment: Perhaps you should increase `times=2` if the results are too variable. Further, the performance issue might be on the Haskell side: are you sure there is no difference between the two Haskell functions, except for the fact that one uses fixed arguments? Try to explicitly let `foo2 = foo1 fixedArg1 fixedArg2` and see if that matters.

Comment: @chi Yes I'm sure. Look at my edit, I have included this piece of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: `unsafe` stuff is `unsafe`.

This code

```hs
readXLSXbig :: SEXP V 'R.Vector
readXLSXbig = unsafePerformIO $ do ...
```

declares a *constant* expression, which will most likely be evaluated only once in the whole program. Each subsequent call after the first one can either re-execute the `do ...` action, or return the previously computed value without re-executing anything.

Essentially, GHC is caching your whole spreadsheet.

`unsafePerformIO action` tells the compiler that we don't care about when `action` is run, or how many times it is run, since the IO `action` will never perform important side effects, and will always return the same result. We are telling the compiler "I know that this is potentially unsafe, but do it anyway -- I'll take the responsibility".

As an ugly, ugly fix, you can add a dummy argument and pray that GHC does not cache previous results.

The actual fix would be to remove the `unsafe` stuff, and return a proper `IO (...)` type. In this way we do not *lie* to the compiler, which will do the right thing. The FFI machinery should still make that callable from R.

Comment: Aaahh that explains why `readXLSXbig` *is slow the first time I call it*. I have a version without `unsafe` but it is slow like `readXLSX`.

Comment: So finally the slowness is the true timing :-( Thanks you @chi, now I better understand `unsafePerformIO`.